# How can I make active parent li on child hover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I added below to make the menu dropdown open on hover. When I move mouse to Menu Item #, the dropdown:hover effect disappear. I need make  active parent li on child hover.

```
.menu{
text-align: center; 
height: 105px;  
border-bottom: 1px solid #676F79;   
} 


.menu > li > a:hover,
.menu > .active > a{
    color: #FFFFFF;     
}   


.menu li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}


<ul class="menu list-inline">                           
        <li class="dropdown">                                   
            <a href="#about" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu text-left">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item #</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item #</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item #</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine as long as the li-elements aren't displayed inline or something like that. Could you provide the CSS or a jsFiddle?